# Change GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle with a binded View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, gridview

I have a binded ListView like so :

```
<ListView Margin="0,10,8,-10" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding PackageBrowser.Documents}" 
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDocument}"
                     View="{Binding PackageBrowser.ColumnConfig, Converter={Converters:ConfigToDynamicGridViewConverter}}">... </ListView>
```

The main purpose of this binding is to generate dynamic column.

Here is my Converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var config = value as ColumnConfig;
        var gridView = new GridView();
        var actualColumn = new GridViewColumn() { Header = "Name", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name") };
        gridView.Columns.Add(actualColumn);

        if (config != null)
        {
            foreach (var column in config.Columns)
            {
                var binding = new Binding(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "ColumnValues[{0}]", column.Name));
                gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = column.Header, DisplayMemberBinding = binding });
            }

            foreach (GridViewColumn c in gridView.Columns)
            {
                // Code below was found in GridViewColumnHeader.OnGripperDoubleClicked() event handler (using Reflector)
                // i.e. it is the same code that is executed when the gripper is double clicked
                // if (adjustAllColumns || App.StaticGabeLib.FieldDefsGrid[colNum].DispGrid)
                if (double.IsNaN(c.Width))
                {
                    c.Width = c.ActualWidth;
                }

                c.Width = double.NaN;
            }  
        }

        return gridView;
    }
```

My question is :
How can I modify the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle of my gridView so all the column cannot be resize.

Something like that but in the code behind :

```
<GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
  </Style>
</GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, You might be written missing code (ColumnHeaderContainerStyle). If you write any style for ColumnHeaderStyle.You must complete all features(If you want to make different designs).For example : Thumb,ContentPresenter etc.I have written a listview style code for you. 
(Sorry,I dont know very well English.I hope this is what you want)

Here is code:

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderGripper" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="Transparent">
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1" Fill="#FFD4D4D4"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>       
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF003362"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFD4D4D4" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1" Name="HeaderBorder" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter Name="HeaderContent" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="0,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-9,0" Style="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderGripper}"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="HeaderContent" Property="Margin" Value="1,1,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" TargetName="HeaderBorder"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Role" Value="Floating">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                        <Canvas Name="PART_FloatingHeaderCanvas">
                            <Rectangle Fill="#60000000" Width="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" Height="{TemplateBinding ActualHeight}"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks MLE for the answer but where can I define the style of the ColumnHeaderContainerStyle? I can't access my grid since it's generate in the code...

Comment: You can write between <Application.Resources> here is style code</Application.Resources>